# external JS files in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to add my js files in my vue project. Below is my main.js. I'm trying to import my js file named nav. when i do that i get saying src\assets\js\nav.js
2:5   error  '$' is not defined  no-undef.

this happens not just for this particular file, it happens for all external js query that I'm trying to add.

//main.js

```
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import App from './App.vue'
    
 import './assets/css/style.css'
 import './assets/css/responsive.css'
    
    
 import './assets/js/nav'
    
 Vue.config.productionTip = false
    
 new Vue({
     render: h => h(App),
 }).$mount('#app')
```

// nav.js

```
// fixed menu on scroll for desktop
if ($(window).width() > 992) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40) {
            $('#header').addClass("fixed-top");
            // add padding top to show content behind navbar
            $('body').css('padding-top', $('.navbar').outerHeight() + 'px');
        } else {
            $('#header').removeClass("fixed-top");
            // remove padding top from body
            $('body').css('padding-top', '0');
        }
    });
} // end if
```

Comment: A quick fix for you could be to append this to the top of nav.js. const $ = window.$; But depending on your build-system, e.g. if this is Webpack, then $ could be added as a global variable.

Comment: thank you, the error is gone now, but my js code for fixed-top doesn't work. I have this same code in html,css and not as a vue project and this works there.

Comment: The content of the nav.js should be executed when the Vue has mounted. You could export a function from nav.js that is executed when Vue has been mounted.